# vue component is not shown

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

i know this has been asked before, but none of the solutions are working for me.

npm is not giving me any errors and if i change the path or mess with the code in any other way, npm will complain. so i am fairly certain that the code is correct, but maybe missing something. the component is just not shown.

from some online tutorial i got the following test component:

```
Vue.component('testcomponent',{
   template : '<div><h1>This is coming from component</h1></div>'
});
```

i would like to use this in another component like this:

```
<template>
    <testcomponent></testcomponent>
</template>

<script>
import testcomponent from "./testcomponent.vue";

export default {
    
    name: "whatever"
    ,components:
    {
         testcomponent
    }
}
```

i also tried loading the component like this:

```
import testcomponent from "./testcomponent.vue";
Vue.component('testcomponent', testcomponent);
```

and like this:

```
Vue.component(
    'passportclients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue').default
);
```

i don't think there is an issue with importing the file as it is also not working when i place the component definition into the same file.

thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Add some text before `<testcomponent></testcomponent>` and maybe try `import { testcomponent } from "./testcomponent.vue";`

Comment: now i got the following warning:
xport 'testcomponent' (imported as 'testcomponent') was not found in './testcomponent.vue' (possible exports: default)

it is still not shown. also i am using vue with laravel. don't know if this might be an issue.

Comment: Do you export something in your file **testcomponent.vue**? And before importing the component. Have you try to put some text to make sure the first component is working?

Comment: what do you mean with "export something"? there is no such keyword in that file. yes, i have added text and the other component is working

Comment: @Patfreeze yes, i added this export default stuff and it is working now, thanks

Comment: A pleasure to help!  Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

in your testcomponent.vue just paste this code

```
<template>
 <div>
  <h1>
   This is coming from component
  </h1>
 </div>
</template>
```

delete everything else